# How do I type 了 with m17n tonepy in ubuntu?

Tags: pinyin, input-methods

I understand this character to be "le1."

Here are what I get for the options of le+tone:

le1:

[image: le1]

le2:

(nothing)

le3:

(nothing)

le4:

[image: le4]

I do not see what I am looking for and expected this common character to be easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is le5 for neutral tone.